# Left pseudo inverse of jacobian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

I am trying to implement the Gauss-Newton algorithm according to the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

In here, the author speaks about calculating the left pseudo inverse of the jacobian matrix.

I have some issues with understanding how to calculate this. I think that the left inverse of a matrix can be calculated like this:

$$(A^TA)^{-1} A^T$$

meaning that we multiply the transpose of matrix A by the inverse of the transpose of matrix A times matrix A.

However, I fail to understand which matrices I need to calculate the pseudo inverse, and what the equation for this would be.

Could someone try to explain this to me?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article, the fact that $(J^T_rJ_r)^{-1}J^T_r$ is the pseudo-inverse of $J_r$ is only a note. The pseudo-inverse is not calculated in practice. Instead, you solve the system of linear equations $\left(J^T_rJ_r\right)\Delta = -J^T_r r(\beta^{(s)})$ and then set $\beta^{(s+1)}=\beta^{(s)}+\Delta.$ Note that it is numerically more stable to solve $\left\|J_r\Delta +r(\beta^{(s)})\right\|_2 = \min$ instead, e.g. with a QR-decomponsition of $J_r$ but that might be out of scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Could you try to elaborate on it for me? I am not quite sure what you mean with the triangle symbol and how to solve your system. Instead of calculating the psuedo inverse of the matrix, I multiply (j_r_t * j_r) with some vector? which would give me the next attempt of the iteration?

Comment: $\Delta$ is just another vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This symbol (actually the uppercase letter Delta in the Greek alphabet) is usually used for the difference of something, in this case $\beta^{(s+1)}-\beta^{(s)}$. In the linear system of equations $(J^T_rJ_r)\Delta = -J^T_r r(\beta^{(s)})$, you know the right-hand side and you know $(J^T_rJ_r)$, which is a square matrix. So you can use one of the ordinary methods to solve systems of linear equations to get $\Delta.$ Then you can get your next $\beta$ and continue with that.

Comment: So matrix A would be (j_r_t * j_r), and vector b would be (-j_r_t * r) * error for each sphere with current sample?

Comment: $A$ and $b$ are exactly as described in the Wikipedia article you cited. I do not know what you mean when you say "* error" or "each sphere". Note that $r\left(\beta^{(s)}\right)$ is not a multiplication of $r$ with something else, but it is the function $r$ evaluated at $\beta^{(s)}$. $J_r$ must also be evaluated at $\beta^{(s)},$ but putting this into the formulae would have made everything really messy.